# In DS-160 do I put my current job now or the cruiseline I will be working on which the visa is for?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, work, cruising

In the education/working/training section of a DS-160 I don't know whether to put my current employment, which I'm going to hand in my notice for, or the cruiseline I'm going to work for (which is why I'm doing the visa)? The embassy doesn't wouldn't contact my current company would they (as I've yet to hand my notice in)?

Comment: Are you applying for C1/D visa (crew member/transit visa) and, if so, do you have an employment contract with the cruise line?

Comment: VTC: absent additional info, not possible to answer.